# iptables: No DNAT on INPUT chain, alternatives?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a process that thinks its local ip address is `192.168.1.101`, running on a host with local ip address `192.168.1.130`. This process is looking for packets sent from a server with ip `80.80.80.80`.

Just to be clear, the process expects incoming packets like this:

- `src_addr`: `80.80.80.80`
- `dst_addr`: `192.168.1.101`

And it sends packets that look like this:

- `src_addr`: `192.168.1.101`
- `dst_addr`: `80.80.80.80`

There's a packet coming in from the server that I need to process, and I can't update the process or allow it to reconnect.

My thought was to use iptables to change the destination address of the packet as its coming in. This meant using either the `PREROUTING` or `INPUT` chains, as it states [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture):

> **Chain Traversal Order**
>
> - Incoming packets destined for the local system: `PREROUTING` -> `INPUT`

This command is exactly what I want:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 80.80.80.80/32 -d 192.168.1.130/32 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101
```

Only, when I run it, I get:

```
x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: used from hooks INPUT, but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT
```

This problem is shown in the [DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture), but no reason is given as to why a rule like that isn't allowed. I also checked the manpage for iptables and it doesn't even mention having an INPUT chain in the nat table, nor does the [netfilter flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), which is confusing.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do and let the process still function, even though it's using a different local ip than the host?

Comment: -t nat -A INPUT need to be -t nat -A PREROUTING

Comment: @c4f4t0r If I do that, then it forwards the packet instead of sending it to the application with the changed ip address, since PREROUTING comes before the routing decision.

Comment: You can simply assign IP address `192.168.1.101` as secondary of `192.168.1.130` and add route `ip route add 80.80.80.80/32 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.101`.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy Nice, I didn't know this existed. Can this extend to multiple processes behaving like this on the same host? Just multiple `ip route add ...` calls?

Comment: @DavidElliott `ip route` work for all process. All process on the host will use `192.168.1.101` source IP address when they try to connect to `80.80.80.80` destination IP address. By example - `ping` command.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy This combined with @c4f4t0r sounds like exactly what I want. Only, when I try your code I'm getting `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`. Do the values need to be anything specific?

Comment: May be you forgot to assign the secondary IP address before adding new route.

Comment: You were right. But it just so happens that I'm running the server on a host with the same ip address as the host I'm running commands from. So when I did `ip address add 192.168.1.101/32 dev eth0` and then `ip route add 80.80.80.80/32 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.101/32`, it made the ssh session I had timeout. I also can't reconnect from any host with ip 80.80.80.80. I can still make changes, but is this normal? I would have thought the original sessions would timeout, but that I would be able to reconnect using the new route.

Comment: Before all use `ping` and `traceroute` programs with debugging by `tcpdump` on both sides.